# Creating an enum instance

Tags: swift, enums

suppose I have

```
enum Example {
  case one(string: String)
  case two(string: String)
}
```

and now I have

```
let x = Example.one(string: "Hello")
```

The question:

```
let y = ?
```

how do I create another instance of the same enum in `e`, so that I end up with `y == .one("World")`)

Comment: Sounds like you want a `struct` instead with two properties, e.g `struct S { enum E { case one, two }; var e: E; var string: String }`.

Comment: Why is it an `enum`? Can't think of a use case here.

Comment: You have a point.

Comment: I like the immutability of the enum, that's why, basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *types* of `enum` cases with associated values are closures with arguments corresponding to the type of the associated values, and with a return corresponding to the type of the `enum` (with the *value* of the return being the specific `case`). I.e., for your example above, the *type* of `Example.one` as well as `Example.two` is `(String) -> Example`, where the closures expressed by these two cases yield different results; *instances* of `.one(...)` and `.two(...)`, respectively.

Hence, instead of writing your own method to "clone" a given case, you could simply have a computed property which returns the already existing closures `Example.one` and `Example.two` (if self is `one` or `two`, respectively), which can subsequently be invoked upon a `String` argument to construct a new `Example` instance (with value `.one` or `.two`; along with the supplied associated `String` value).

E.g.:

```
enum Example {
    case one(string: String) // type: (String) -> Example
    case two(string: String) // type: (String) -> Example

    var caseClosure: (String) -> Example {
        switch self {
        case .one: return Example.one
        case .two: return Example.two
        }
    }
}

let x = Example.one(string: "Hello") // .one("Hello")
let y = x.caseClosure("World")       // .one("World")
```

However, since all the cases in your example are closures of the same type, namely `(String) -> Example` (i.e. have the same number and type(s) of associated values), you might as well, [as already proposed in a comment by @Hamish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48078075/creating-an-enum-instance#comment83130178_48078075), wrap an `enum` with no associated values in a `struct` along with the always-`String` "associated value" a separate member of the `struct`. E.g. expanding Hamish's example with some initializers:

```
struct S {
    enum E {
        case one
        case two
    }
    var e: E
    var string: String // Since "associated value" is always the same type
    init(_ e: E, string: String) {
        self.e = e
        self.string = string
    }
    init(from s: S, string: String) {
        self.e = s.e
        self.string = string
    }
}

let x = S(.one, string: "Hello")
let y = S(from: x, string: "World")
let z = S(x.e, string: "World")
```

Answer (score 1):

You do that by calling the Initializer exactly like you did for `x`:

```
enum Example {
    case one(string: String)
    case two(string: String)
}

let x = Example.one(string: "Hello")
print(x) // Prints one("Hello")

let y = Example.one(string: "World")
print(y) // Prints one("World")
```

Also, The `,` in your enum declaration is wrong and has to be removed.

---

**UPDATE:**

The comment explained the question in more detail, so here is my updated answer:

An elegant way to solve this is to use a function on the original enum type `Example`.

```
enum Example {
    case one(string: String)
    case two(string: String)

    func cloneWith(string: String) -> Example {
        switch self {
        case .one:
            return .one(string: string)
        case .two:
            return .two(string: string)
        }
    }
}

let x = Example.one(string: "Hello")
print(x) // Prints one("Hello")

let y = x.cloneWith(string: "World")
print(y) // Prints one("World")
```

Comment: Not my intention: what I want is to create an in Y the same enum as for X, without knowing which one it is.